# CSS in HTML Email

Tags: css, html-email

I need to update an old email template. In the old template, which are like 4-5 years old, I found stuff like

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" class="bodyTable">
```

Now I am not sure why they used the those syntax, just because it is old, or is there any other mail-template related reason? Can I change them without any concern into, let's say:

```
<table style="text-align:center;border:0;height:100%; width:100%" class="bodyTable">
```

If not, can someone maybe explain to me why?

Comment: if you want you can change, no issues

Comment: _“If not, can someone maybe explain to me why?”_ - that alone would justify closing this question as too broad IMHO. HTML e-mail is a complex topic, at lot has been written about that already - so please do some proper reading up on the topic, if you run into any issues.

Comment: Emails clients are not good at rendering HTML, using the old HTML attributes may be a more reliable solution if the recipients might be using older versions of email clients

Comment: Read the long answers below, in short: Outlook is the most troublesome email client and doesnt ready styles on elements the right way. I advice to keep it but ditch `height="100%"`. it has weird outcomes in Apple mail (atleast in Litmus)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is, or at the least was, the recommended style for HTML emails. For instance, "HTML attributes instead of CSS" are advised by [Smash Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/01/introduction-building-sending-html-email-for-web-developers). While CSS support is gradually improving, there is no universal HTML email standard, so each email client supports its own subset of HTML/CSS. Thus, email designers are advised to  'think 99' or post-process their email templates with special inlining/downgrading tools, such as
 http://premailer.dialect.ca (and a few [others](https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-css-inlining-in-email)).

I'd say CSS has been well supported by major email clients for several year, yet, say in 2011 I find occasional stackoverflow complains of gmail.com stripping styles attributes [HTML email in Gmail - CSS style attribute removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602400/html-email-in-gmail-css-style-attribute-removed).

So I guess authors opted to play save. It is not uncommon for companies to care even of users stuck with somewhat outdated software.

According to [this list](https://medium.com/@ranadeepbhuyan/supported-html-tags-in-common-email-clients-2cc11e1ae283), the major and current email clients support the style attribute well. Still, there is always a risk that a particular tag, attribute, or their combination are not supported by a less know email client, sometimes due to a bug or a corner case, as you can see in a relatively recent post regarding Spark client [HTML Email formatting stripped out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118551/html-email-formatting-stripped-out).

Comment: Another great resource is campaign monitors css support list found here: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/tables/table-layout/.